# Instantiate Variables In a Class

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm currently working on an Ionic / Angular based app and was wondering what the different methods for instantiating a variable actually mean. Have done and seen it a few different ways and I'm not sure what any of these three scenarios actually do:

```
export class someClass {
  myVariable: string
  ...

  someFunction() {
     // Accessed without issue without needing to instantiate.
     this.myVariable = 'foo';
  }
}
```

When done this way is it just giving me a default string object that I'm then overwriting with "foo"?

```
export class someClass {
  appService: AppService
  constructor(appService: AppService) {
     // No idea what this means as opposed to excluding it from the constructor.
     this.appService = appService;
  }
}
```

When done this way what am I actually setting this.appService to? Is that just duplicate/redundant instances?

```
export class someClass {
  constructor(private storage: Storage) {}
  
  async getSomeVariable(): Promise<any> {
     // Mentioned as a parameter in the constructor 
    // but never set to anything or defined as a variable outside of the constructor?
     return await this.storage.get('someVariable');
  }
}
```

When done this way is it just instantiating a default instance of "Storage" and that's what I'm accessing later on in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example:

```
export class someClass {
  myVariable: string
  ...

  someFunction() {
     // Accessed without issue without needing to instantiate.
     this.myVariable = 'foo';
  }
}
```

`someClass` has a property called `myVariable` that is sitting there eagerly ready and waiting to hold some value for you. For now, it's `undefined`.
In `someFunction()`, it gets to fulfil its purpose in life and can finally hold the value `foo` for you. Its life is now complete.
This is basic, standard class-level properties that are found in most languages. E.g. C#:

```
public class SomeClass {
  private string _myVariable;

  public void SomeFunction() {
    _myVariable = "foo";
  }
}
```

Your second example:

```
export class someClass {
  appService: AppService
  constructor(appService: AppService) {
     // No idea what this means as opposed to excluding it from the constructor.
     this.appService = appService;
  }
}
```

This is a waste of code, with respect to how Angular injects things and how it stores that coming in. By injecting the `AppService`, Angular is magically also storing that for the class so that it's available as `this.appService`.
My typical version is to prefix as `private readonly` because... why would you be changing something you're injecting?

```
constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) { }
```

Without any prefixing, it's public (and not readonly), but the above means it's only available to the class (private) and something can't overwrite it (readonly). It's a preference, but notice the body of the constructor is empty; Angular has magically stored it and left it available to me.
More C# exampling; C# doesn't do this kind of thing automagically, you have to do something just like that example yourself:

```
public class SomeClass {
  private readonly AppService _appService;

  public SomeClass(AppService appService) {
    _appService = appService;
  }
}
```

But again, not necessary with Angular.

Finally, your third example:

```
export class someClass {
  constructor(private storage: Storage) {}
  
  async getSomeVariable(): Promise<any> {
     // Mentioned as a parameter in the constructor 
    // but never set to anything or defined as a variable outside of the constructor?
     return await this.storage.get('someVariable');
  }
}
```

Frankly, it's a continuation of your second example. Angular has pulled out (or created a new instance of) the `Storage` class for your class to use (if you're not familiar with dependency injection and/or Angular's implementation thereof, go ahead and check out their [docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) on the subject).
It has then automagically saved that as the `storage` variable in the background, and that's what the method content is then accessing.

Overall, I think you have the basic idea of what it's doing in each case, but in each case Angular's particular implementation has muddied the waters of understanding so that you're never quite sure.

Similar things happen in reverse (again, C#). Take C#'s shorthand for public/private getters and setters:

```
public string Something { get; set; }
public string SomethingElse { get; private set; }
// etc.
```

Nice one-liners.
In Angular (more accurately, TypeScript), they don't have the one liners, you have to write:

```
private _something: string;
public get something(): string { return this._something; }
```

Two lines. This is also, technically, what C# does behind the scenes for you.

```
private string _something;
public string Something { 
  get { return _something; } 
  set { _something = value; }
}
```

In this same way, Angular hides those extra lines in the background for you with injecting into the constructor, per your examples.